# text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server to show if field1 is null then field2, if field1 and field2 are null then field3, if field1, field2, field3 are null then field4 if all 4 fields are null then NULL  How would this be displayed in SQL Server?  I am assuming maybe a case statement and do case when etc but I am lost on this.

EDIT --
I tried running a straight COALESCE function like suggested and I get an error
The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

```
Select
Count(SoldNum),
Coalesce(Store1, Store2, Store3, Store4) As Store_Item_Sold_From
ItemSoldBy
ItemSold
FROM salesDatabase
Where Sold Is not null
Group By ItemSoldBy, ItemSold, Coalesce(Store1, Store2, Store3, Store4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

COALESCE Evaluates the arguments in order and returns the current value of the first expression that initially does not evaluate to NULL.

```
SELECT COALESCE(field1, field2, field3, field4) FROM yourtable
```

## [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)

Or You can use CASE Statement

```
SELECT CASE WHEN field1 IS NULL THEN Field2
            WHEN Field1 IS NULL AND Field2 IS NULL Then Field3
            WHEN Field1 IS NULL AND Field2 IS NULL AND Field3 IS NULL Then Field4
            ELSE 'NIL'
            END
```

Comment: Why suggesting `case` here?

Comment: That won't fix the error.  The problem is the `GROUP BY` on the text type, not the `COALESCE()`.  You can't sort by a text type.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for the [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) operator

```
SELECT COALESCE(field1, field2, field3, field4)
```

Comment: When I run this I get the following error:    The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

Comment: Try posting more of your code so we can more clearly see what your issue is.

Comment: You are talking about the field that is text, ntext and image which is not sorted with like operator or isnull function. The best way to go is either Case statement or depending on the condition you can use  Coalesce function which will do the same thing as isnull does but with more null options.

Comment: You can't coalesce columns that are of type text/ntext and image together.  Do you really need one of your columns to be of type image?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [coalesce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) function

```
SELECT COALESCE(field1, field2, field3, field4) FROM Table
```

If all four fields are null then your final result will be null. Unless of course you were to add a default:

```
SELECT COALESCE(field1, field2, field3, field4, 'Not Found') FROM Table
```

Answer (score 1):

**Don't use `text` for this. Use `varchar`**

The problem is not because of COALESCE(), it's because of grouping by a text (or image) field.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (a text)
SELECT a FROM @t GROUP BY a

Msg 306, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.
```

Text/ntext/image types are not sortable like numbers or varchar.  If you have a bunch of books, you wouldn't put "Fahrenheit 451" next to "The Bell Jar", because their first words are "It was a p..." and "It was a q...".  You wouldn't sort images by the color of the first pixel. Use a `text`/`image` field to hold the contents of a book/picture and a `varchar` field to hold the title.  Then sort by the title.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know COALESCE will not work for this case because the sort is in ntext or text field and they might be null or not null.

I think what you can do is CASE Statement like this:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),Field1) IS NULL THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),Field2)
WHEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),Field1) IS NULL AND CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),Field2) THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),Field3)
WHEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),Field1) IS NULL AND CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),Field2) AND CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),Field3) THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),Field4)
WHEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),Field4) IS NULL THEN Field4 END
    FROM YOURTABLE
```

**NOTE:** You can use datatype depending on your case and you can change conditions `AND`, `OR` operators as well